# I can't change global variable inside setInterval es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, settimeout, setinterval, es6-promise

I have to find a button when it will appear. In order to do that I use setInterval. When it finds this button, it gives to my variable needed value. I check it inside the setTimeout, but after setTimeout(outside these method) my global variable became as before setTimeout. How to fix that?

```
let foundValue;
function findById(id) {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.getElementById(id)){
      let foundValue = document.getElementById(id);
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
  return foundValue;
}
```

Comment: You have two `let foundValue` lines. Is it intentional?

Comment: remove 2nd let ..........

Comment: Essentially, you have two variables in different scopes called the same thing

Comment: I deleted these let. Situation has not changed

Comment: Are you checking `foundValue` after the interval, or are you checking the value returned by `findById`, because the way you `return` there is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I found that I return before setinterval found button, but how should i wait for end of interval?

Comment: @TeymurGasanov You [cannot wait and `return`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're re-declaring `foundValue` inside `setInterval` so you should remove the second `let`, for example:

```
let foundValue;
function findById(id) {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.getElementById(id)){
      foundValue = document.getElementById(id);
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
  return foundValue;
}
```

Comment: I deleted these let but nothing happened

Comment: It's working for me as follows `console.log(foundInterval) // is undefined` then `findById('element_id')` then `console.log(foundInterval) // contains element`